# Is there a stack exchange site for aquarium management?

Tags: discussion

i.e. fish biology, marine chemistry for aquatic habitats, etc.?

Just wondering. Would be a nice community. Biology is the closest I can think of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would turn to [**Pets.SE**](https://pets.stackexchange.com/), as they feature an [**aquarium**](https://pets.stackexchange.com/tags/aquarium/info) tag.